# TypeError in Devise/passwords#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting a weird error with devise when a user tries to reset their password.
The error reads;

```
TypeError in Devise/passwords#edit

Showing /var/www/html/webapp/app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb where line #8 raised:

Extracted source (around line #8): 
can't convert Symbol into Integer



<%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>
6:   <%= f.input :password, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Password" %>
7:   <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: false, placeholder: "Confirm Password" %>
8:   <%= f.input :submit , "Change Password" %>
9: <% end %>
10: 
11: <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: full stacktrace of the error including line number would be useful

Comment: @Vimsha, added some information

Comment: Shouldn't line 8 be `f.button :submit, "Change Password"` or `f.submit "Change Password"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>Change your password</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :reset_password_token, :as => :hidden %>
  <%= f.full_error :reset_password_token %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :password, :label => "New password", :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => "Confirm your new password", :required => true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Change my password" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

**This is my views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb file. Fix yours now.**

Answer (score 0):

Change line 8 to `f.button`

```
<%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>
   <%= f.input :password, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Password" %>
   <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: false, placeholder: "Confirm Password" %>
   <%= f.button :submit , "Change Password" %>
 <% end %>

 <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```